# PHP Regular Expression to replace html img tag with [IMG]

Tags: php, html, regex, image

I have the following regular expression to replace an html img tag with [IMG];

```
echo preg_replace('/(^<img) (.*) (>$)/i', '[IMG]', $subject);
```

It works as expected to a certain extent, however some of the img tags I'm working end with '/>' and some end with '>'. I can't get the above to work with the latter.

Sample 1 (works):

```
<img src="image-1.gif" alt="image-1" width="175>" height="80" />
```

Sample 2 (doesn't work)

```
<img src="image-2.gif" width="77" height="51" alt="image-2">
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: That's why regular expressions are not optimal for parsing PHP. Consider using a HTML parser instead. [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)

Comment: Is sample 1 itentionally corrupt HTML or did you mean `...width="175" height="80" />`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Pekka is right to say you should use an HTML parser (I completely agree), for education's sake, you can use the 'optional' character, `?`, which marks the previous character as optional:

```
echo preg_replace('/(^<img) (.*)(\\\?>$)/i', '[IMG]', $subject);
```

Notice `\\\?`. We escape the backslash and question marl (with a backslash) and then say 'this character is optional'.

Comment: My bad, needed an extra escape. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest fetching the URL and then manually writing the [IMG] tag.

e.g.

```
preg_match('/src="(.*?)"/', '<img src="image-2.gif" width="77" height="51" alt="image-2">', $matches)
echo '[IMG]'.$matches[1].'[/IMG]';
```

Shai.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a DOM parser. They're much more reliable.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Answer (score 0):

for example we have string like this :- `$str = 'Text <img src="hello.png" > hello <img src="bye.png" /> other text.`

so then we can do replace img tag like below

**STEP 1**

```
$str = 'Text <img src="hello.png" > hello <img src="bye.png" /> other text.';
if(preg_match("/(<img .*>)/i", $str)){
     $img_array = preg_split('/(<img .*>)/i', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
}
```

**This will output:**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Text "
  [1]=>
  string(22) "<img src="hello.png" >"
  [2]=>
  string(7) " hello "
  [3]=>
  string(21) "<img src="bye.png" />"
  [4]=>
  string(12) " other text."
}
```

**STEP 2** then we will to do replace in for loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($img_array); $i++){
     $url = "welcome.png";
     $img_array[$i] = preg_replace('/(<img .*>)/i', '<img src="'.$url.'" alt="'.$url.'">', $img_array[$i]); //replace src path & alt text
}
```

**STEP 3** then after convert array to string

```
$str = implode('', $img_array);
```

then after you will get **final output** like this

```
$str = 'Text <img src="welcome.png" > hello <img src="welcome.png" /> other text.';
```